# Context.getString(@StringRes int resId) returns the default string no matter the locale

Tags: android, xml, localization, android-resources

I am working on an ongoing project and I was asked to add localization to that app.

I added the right xml files to the project for different languages yet when I change the language on the emulator it still gets the default string, I tried the same configuration a new project and it works just fine.

My question is what could it possibly be that makes this bug happen?

So far:

I checked the files and their names (meaning I checked the directory they are in and tried names like values-en and values-en_US)

I checked if someone changes the Locale to default.

In debug when I call Locale.getDefault() it returns the right language but getString() still returns the default strings.

Also checked if strings are hardcoded

Comment: maybe the strings are hardcoded in your layout?

Comment: I checked that too, :(

Comment: are you forcing programmatically the locale of the device?

Comment: no, I am changing the language of the emulator, and I just created a new project with the same xml files in the same paths and it worked